# Static declaration follows non-static declaration, but no functions declared statically

Tags: c, declaration

I have code similar to the following:

```
void interact();
int main( int arg_count, const char* args[] ){
    tty_save();                 /* save current terminal mode */
    interact();                 /* interact with user */
    tty_restore();              /* restore terminal to the way it was */
    return 0;
}

void interact(){
    /* do various stuff */
}
```

I don't see where the "static declaration is". I declare the function once (non-statically) before main() and then define the function after main(), once again, non-statically. Why am I getting this compile error?

The error is "Static declaration of interact() follows non-static declaration".

Comment: Which line is the error pointing to?

Comment: I think your problem is not in the code presented.

Comment: are you sure error refers to `interact()` ?

Comment: I think you should post the full warning text

Comment: ... And full code.. Or MCVE.

Comment: Your error can't be reproduced with the posted code.  Please post the **full** code, along with the compiler / version you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of error frequently occurs when either accidentally or deliberately one function is included inside of another one, which is not normally allowed in C. Often this occurs because there is an unmatched leading brace either in the file itself or in one of the other files in the same translation unit which are being included via headers. The mismatched brace could be occurring either in an included prototype or in the body of a definition. For example, if you had a syntax error in a prototype like the following:

```
void stringInsertChars( BUFFER* buffer, const char* c ){
```

instead of...

```
void stringInsertChars( BUFFER* buffer, const char* c );
```

then it could cause the error, which by itself is misleading. Here, what has happened is that the prototype has been copied from the definition, but the coder forgot to change `{` to `;`.

The way to detect this problem is to carefully examine the whole body of the error message. If a mismatched brace is the problem, then you will see the error read like this:

```
File mycode.c in function stringInsertChars 46:
    Static declaration of interact() follows non-static declaration....
    (more errors of the same type)
```

So, the error message will tell you which prototype (or definition) has the extra brace.